# Using Synergy With Logitech MX Master, OS X

Tags: macos, mouse, synergy, imac

First, my setup: 
Server machine: Retina 5K 27-inch iMac, OS X El Capitan 10.11.2, Logitech MX Master. I am mapping the buttons solely using BetterTouch Tool. I do not have Logitech Options or Logitech Control Center installed. I am using Karabiner to remap my keyboard too. All is working fine on this machine. 
Client machine: Late-2013 27-inch iMac, OS X El Capitan 10.11.2. I'm also using BetterTouch Tool to remap the buttons here and would like them to be the same here as they are on the server computer. Whenever I click Button 3 and try to change it, it activates Mission Control but I cannot find anywhere where it's already been mapped to do that. Additionally if I click the middle button on the MX Master on a client machine, it activates TotalSpaces2 Overview, which is also not set in the software to do so.

My question: Is it possible to use something like BetterTouch Tool to remap the buttons from a virtual mouse on a client with Synergy?